# Akka 2.0 Remoting: How do I start/allocate remote actors at runtime

Tags: scala, akka

Using akka 1.3.1, I was able to previously do something like this:

`Actor.remote.start(config.server.host, config.server.port)
Actor.remote.register("service", Actor.actorOf[ServiceHandler].start())`

Which would start a remote server using the provided host/port configuration, and then allow me to register remote services later on during runtime. Is there any way to get this behavior in Akka 2.0 without having to predefine everything in the akka conf files?

Thanks!

Comment: I hope we can get a fully working example for this question...that would be awesome to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your actors are reachable automatically by path in the remoting in 2.0. Read documentation on remoting here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/scala/remoting.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Victor! I see that Akka 2.0 makes the registration of services obsolete....however is there any way to start the akka remote server at runtime with a specified host/port? (This would correspond to the first line in the code sample)

Comment: Hi Bryan, instructions for enabling and configuring the remoting is outlined in the link in my response.